# Solution check. How many relations of equivalence $R$ are there in $\Bbb N$ that verify silmultaneously the following properties.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

I'm revising some old psets while preparing an exam and going through some things that I left unverified.

How many relations of equivalence $R$ are there in $\Bbb N$ that verify silmultaneously the following properties?

- If two elements end in the same digit, they are related
- {(1,2),(101,25),(4,4),(234,20166),(22,7),(153,158),(8,100),(17,27)}$⊆R$
- (1,14),(32,8),(19,10),(309,666) $\notin R$

This would give me the following equivalence classes if I'm not wrong:

$[1] = [2] = [5] = [7]$

$[0] = [3] = [8]$

$[4] = [6]$

$[9]$

The thing is that I'm not understanding how to use the third property, so that makes me think I got the previous wrong. Can you help me out?

Comment: The third property is strange. I interpret the first property in the way that only numbers with the same ending digits are related. In this case, the pairs given in property $3$ are not related. So, it would not matter to rule them out ...

Comment: Also in property $2$, two pairs are already related by property $1$.

Comment: @Peter they need to have all of the properties at the same time... that's why I've "mixed" the equivalence classes of the first two. But... I don't really know if this is what the problem is asking for.

Comment: How do you know $[0]\ne [4]$, or that $[9]\ne [1]$? As far as I can see, there is no way to show that(?).

Comment: @Szmagpie the only elements that are in the relation are those who share the last digit and those of the set in the second property. So, for instance the class of 1 and 2 are related respectively to every other number that ends in 1 and 2. But the pair (1,2) is also in R so they must be related between them as well... that's how I thought it at least.

Comment: I have read it as "How many different equivalence relations are there on $\Bbb{N}$ that satisfy these properties?", In which case I believe you have demonstrated one such relation, another would have classes $\{[0],[1]\}$, another would have classes $\{[0],[1],[9]\}$, etc. Note that the relation with classes $\{[0],[1]\}$ *does* satisfy all three properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer starts where you stopped. We focus on the $4$ sets $[1],[0],[4],[9]$. Any equivalence relation with the mentioned properties will induce a partition such that each of its elements is a non-empty union of these sets.

We have $[1]\cup[0]\cup[4]\cup[9]=\mathbb N$, but what can be said about mutually disjointness? On this the third property applies the following information:

- $[1]\cap[4]=\varnothing$
- $[1]\cap[0]=\varnothing$
- $[0]\cap[9]=\varnothing$
- $[4]\cap[9]=\varnothing$

Note that $[1]\cap[9]\neq\varnothing$ or equivalently $[1]=[9]$ is *not* excluded.

Also note that $[0]\cap[4]\neq\varnothing$ or equivalently $[0]=[4]$ is *not* excluded.

This makes $4$ partitions possible:

- $\{[1],[0],[4],[9]\}$
- $\{[1],[0],[4]\}$ where $[1]=[9]$
- $\{[1],[0],[9]\}$ where $[0]=[4]$
- $\{[1],[0]\}$ where $[0]=[4]$ and $[1]=[9]$

The answer on the original question (number of equivalences) is $4$.